# Error Uploading/Downloading files to/from Portable Device using

Tags: c#, tablet, mediadevices

I'm trying to to upload and download files from Android Samsung tablet in an infinite loop.

a sample code is

```
while(true){
 var devices = MediaDevice.GetDevices();
using (var device = devices.First())
{

device.Connect();
device.UploadFile(@"C:/Inbox/file.pdf", @"\Tablet\Inbox\file.pdf");
device.Disconnect();

}

System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
//I manually delete the file from folder before the next iteration
}//while
```

The problem as follows:
in the first iteration the file is uploaded, and when I physically delete the file from the tablet (inbox folder is empty) and trying to upload the file again I get an exception that file is exist, however, the tablet's inbox folder is empty.

The problem is same when downloading the file. in the first iteration the file is downloaded, but when another file is created physically on tablet, then the:
 device.EnumerateFiles(@"\Tablet\Outbox\"); 
returns empty list.

how can I solve this problem?

Comment: What exact exception is thrown (`Type` and `StackTrace`) on what exact line?

Comment: Also, tell us why you are trying to do this? Why are you uploading files, deleting them, uploading them again etc etc?

Comment: System.IO file 'file.pdf' already exists,

I'm not deleting the files manually, there is a service running in the tablet in that takes each file in inbox and adding some tags to it and then it saves the new file in the outbox folder, and deletes the original one from the inbox, so its kind of a sync over usb

Comment: The exception is thrown in UploadFile().
The second problem is that there is a file in the outbox folder but the PC doesn't find id and returns that the folder is empty.